# C#: Confusion about Interfaces, Implementation and Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, implementation

I'm wondering about what's the way to go, if I need to publicate data-interfaces but want to use them internal with extended calculated properties. To make it clearer:

```cs
// The public interface
public interface IData
{
    int Property { get; }
}

// The internal interface
internal interface IExtendedData : IData
{
    int ExtendedProperty { get; }
}

// The assumed implementation of someone using my interface
public class Data : IData
{
    public Data(int a)
    {
        Property = a;
    }

    public int Property
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Property.ToString();
    }
}

// My implementation
internal class ExtendedData : IExtendedData
{
    public ExtendedData(int a)
    {
        Property = a;
    }

    public int Property
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int ExtendedProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 2 * Property;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Property.ToString() + ExtendedProperty.ToString();
    }
}

// publicated by me, for the person who uses my dll
public static class Calculations
{
    public static int DoSomeCalculation(IData data, int parameter)
    {
        // This probably don't work, but maybe shows what I want to do
        IExtendedData tempData = (ExtendedData)data;
        return tempData.ExtendedProperty * parameter;
    }
}
```

I'm realy frustrated, cause I feel like missing some basical programing skills.

Comment: The person using your dll would not have access to IExtendedData and ExtendData as they are declared as internal to your assembly/dll.

Comment: If `Calculations` were declared in the same assembly as the `IExtendedData` and `ExtendedData` internals, this would work fine. :)

Comment: Of course. The person will only implement himself the IData interface. In my exaple his implementation would be the class "Data". He only will call the static DoSomething-method and pass his "Data"-object. But I need, due to some complexity, extensional properties. I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You could solve this problem by implementing ExtendedData as a Wrapper for a class implementing IData

```
internal class ExtendedData : IExtendedData
{

    private IData data;
    public ExtendedData(IData data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int Property
    {
        get { return data.Property; }
        private set { data.Property = value; }
    }

    public int ExtendedProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 2 * Property;
        }
    }    
}
```

and use this in `DoSomeCalculation` like

```
 IExtendedData tempData = new ExtendedData(data);
```

Comment: Almost posted the same answer before seeing yours. It can solve the problem perfectly.:)

Comment: I was worried about that :( ... This meens a lot of work for me, because there are lots and lots of properties in those data interfaces and I was hoping that there's a easier way to map them

Comment: I believe you could use class inheriting from DynamicObject as a generic wrapper to avoid reimplementing every property in IData, but you'd loose IntelliSense and (a lot of) runtime performance.

Comment: Another option might be to define extension methods for IData doing you calculation. You'd have methods instead of properties then, like `data.GetExtendedProperty()`

Comment: :) Yea, with your proposal of extension methods the three ways to go, I thought about myself are complete: Wraping myself, forcing to use a factory and extension methods. I think dynamic is not realy an option for me at this point. Is there anything I missed? What would be the best way to go? Probably there's no best practice, and I have to decide by myself based on the particular case, right?

Comment: Done this before. With a clever tool like Resharper or Refactor Pro this is a lot less work than it seems.

Comment: @Lindan: What in particular did you do with Resharper? What feature did you use to do what?

Answer (score 0):

ExtendedData could inherit from Data:

```
class ExtendedData : Data
{...}
```

And for creation of a `Data` object you add a factory like so:

```
public class DataFactory
{
    public IData CreateData()
    {
        return new ExtendedData();
    }
}
```

User have to create all its *Data* objects by this factory. You can ensure it by making *Data*'s constructor internal.
In your DLL you can then cast to `ExtendedData`.

Comment: I already thought about that, too. But this will force the person using my assembly to write himself a wrapper. Assuming this person gets a data-class from a database. If he then just implement in this class the interface, he would be able to pass it without any further wrapping. But obviously I will have to go one wraping way... by myself or forcing him, right?